# how to change color for dialogue windows

Tags: unity

I've been having issues with my interface (messed up colors, menus, and so on). i have deleted the .gnome folder, .gconf, .gconfd.

Some issues are still there especially with ambiance theme, I could get it fixed by installing some alternative ambiance themes (ambiance-blue, ambiance-red, etc).

The issue that I cannot fix yet is the color of dialogue windows' text. the background is grey, the text is white. Where can I find such setting?

[image: Messed up dialogues]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the gtk.css file in the theme's folder. You'll see 'fg_color' line. Change the color to something dark like "#000000"

Comment: in my ~/.themes folder?

Comment: the gtk.css is located in the Ambiance theme folder

Comment: this is what i have: 

alex@alex-ubuntu:~/.themes/Ambiance$ ls
gtk-2.0  gtk-3.0  index.theme  metacity-1  unity

Comment: haha sorry I forgot to tell ya. It is in /Ambiance/gtk-3.0/ folder

Comment: ok thx, there seem to be lots of settings in there, I'm going to have good fun :)

Comment: can I also ask where are themes located other than ~/.themes?

Comment: Where can i find a default ambiance css?  :D I kind of messed it up eheheh

Comment: gtk-widgets.css and gtk.css in /Ambiance/gtk-3.0/ folder

Comment: Do you guys know if it's possible to download a clean ambiance folder from somewhere?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/light-themes

Comment: A better way, without messing with any of your themes internal files, is just to create `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. Anything you put in there will override everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Install gnome-tweak-tool and it has option to change theme,icon,cursor try it am not sure it might help

Comment: I can't seem to find such setting

Comment: If you change those themes and settings it change these colours thats why i posted it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install other GTK+ themes and have a try.

themes folder can be at *~/.themes*(personal setting) or */usr/share/themes*(global setting)